# Simple Makefile doesn't clean

Tags: makefile

I have this Makefile:

```
default:
    mv presentacion.pdf /tmp
    pdflatex presentacion.tex

clean:
    rm -f *.{aux,log,nav,out,snm,toc}
```

The order make works well but when I try to do a make clean the shell outputs:

> rm -f *.{aux,log,nav,out,snm,toc}

And does not remove the files. What's wrong in the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to set the shell to bash in your makefile (according [docs](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Choosing-the-Shell.html))

```
SHELL=/bin/bash

default:
    mv presentacion.pdf /tmp
    pdflatex presentacion.tex

clean:
    rm -f *.{aux,log,nav,out,snm,toc}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can let `make` add the prefix to your files (instead of `bash`), by using `addprefix`:

```
PREFIXES := aux log nav out snm toc
FILES := $(addprefix *., $(PREFIXES))

default:
        mv presentacion.pdf /tmp
        pdflatex presentacion.tex

clean:
        rm -f $(FILES)
```